# java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object(Tried closing )

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public int getRecordsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
            cursor.close();
        }   
        // return count

        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

I am trying to get the totalnumber of records in the database, but the database is getting crashed everytime with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT  * FROM login)` . Please help me with the error

```
  03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT  * FROM login) 
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:34)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:64)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:283)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:264)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.ecomm.android.sqlite.DatabaseHandler.getRecordsCount(DatabaseHandler.java:123)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.ecomm.android.LaunchActivity.DataBaseImplementation(LaunchActivity.java:120)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.ecomm.android.LaunchActivity.onClick(LaunchActivity.java:98)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
    03-05 22:23:14.208: E/AndroidRuntime(4988):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-05 22:23:15.608: I/binder_sample(4988): [android.app.IActivityManager,2,1395,com.ecomm.android,100]
    03-05 22:23:15.608: I/binder_sample(4988): Unknown binary event type 110
    03-05 22:23:15.608: I/binder_sample(4988): Binary log entry conversion failed
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should call `getCount()` before you close your cursor.

Move:

```
if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
    cursor.close();
}
```

below:

```
 cursor.getCount();
```

like this:

```
public int getRecordsCount() {
    int count = 0;
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);



    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
        count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
    }   
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed

Your error is thrown because you call `cursor.getCount()` on `Cursor` that you already close and this is not allowed.

So either try to use **try-finally** block where in finally block you close your `Cursor` or assign `cursor.getCount()` to int value and close `Cursor` immediately.

But i recommend to you use first approach:

```
public int getRecordsCount() {
   String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
   int count = 0;
   try {
      if (cursor.moveToFirst())) {
         count = cursor.getCount();
      }
      return count;
   }
   finally {
      if (cursor != null) {
         cursor.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the `cursor.close()` statement

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but my problem ended up being that in `onCreate()`, I was calling `db.close()` after executing `db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE)`.

`onCreate` is automatically called after `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()`.

This caused it to crash because then it went to retrieve all the values from the database with an already-closed object. Once I removed `db.close()` from `onCreate`, it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was that I was closing the db instance in the finally block for the update query.

For people who are not able to fix using the above solution, try checking your update query.